# Recursive Regex, capture same text under two different tags

Tags: regex

I am looking to parse some text using regex, and I need to be able to grab the same text under two different tags while only capturing text before a certain character on the second tag. Here is a sample of the text I'm trying to bring in.

```
Reputation=High risk ProtocolP=SSL client Web_Application=YouTube URL=https://youtube.com
```

And here is the RegEx I have written so far.

```
^Reputation=(?<rep>.*?)\sProtocol=(?<prot>.*?)\sWeb_Application=(?<webapp>.*?)\sURL=(?<url>[http|https].*?)\sSource_IP=(?<sip>.*?)\s
```

This gets me what I need initially, but I need to add a second tag for the URL section to grab ONLY the domain name. For example, only `https://youtube.com`

Of course, if the domain happens to be `https://m.youtube.com` then that should be captured as well.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `Reputation=High risk ProtocolP=SSL client Web_Application=YouTube URL=https://youtube.com`  this is the raw data. No, unfortunately I do not have XML fragment parsing ability.

Comment: Try changing `URL=(?<url>[http|https].*?)` with `URL=(?<url>(?:http|https)://(?<domain>[^/]+).*?)`. See https://regex101.com/r/pB0tN7/1

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working for some reason. 
I have this that sort of works sometimes `URL=(?<url>https?://(?<domain>[^/s]+)(?:/[^s]+)?)\s+`     The problem is it is extremely hit and miss in what it captures. Sometimes it gets both the URL and the domain, sometimes nothing at all. https:// with nothing past the / after the domain name, or sometimes its http:// within nothing past the / after the domain name. I'm not sure how to guarantee the URL and domain are captured every time

Comment: Try [`URL=(?<url>https?://(?<domain>[^/\s]+)(?:/[^\s]+)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/pB0tN7/2) - you omitted the ``\`` before `s` and you need `/` in the first negated character class.

Comment: That was EXACTLY what I was looking for. This works like a CHAMP! Thank you very very much.

Comment: I posted the pattern with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the URL matching part with `URL=(?<url>https?://(?<domain>[^/\s]+)(?:/[^\s]+)*)`:

```
Reputation=(?<rep>.*?)\sProtocolP=(?<prot>.*?)\sWeb_Application=(?<webapp>.*?)\sURL=(?<url>https?://(?<domain>[^/\s]+)(?:/\S+)*)\sSource_IP=(?<sip>.*?)\s
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pB0tN7/3)

- `https?://` - matches `http://` or `https://`
- `(?<domain>[^/\s]+)` - domain matching part, 1+ characters other than `/` and whitespace
- `(?:/\S+)*` - 0+ sequences of `/` followed with 1+ characters other than whitespace